# Where to put DSet DataAccess logic using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

I'm using CodeFirst EF6 and I'd like to place all related "queries" into a single class.

Let's say I have a

```
DbSet<Car> Cars;
```

in my DbContext.

I tried to create a new class with my concrete DbSet as base class:

```
public class CarRepository : DbSet<Car>
```

in which I'd locate all car related operations.

When I replace DbSet with CarRepository in my DbContext class it won't get filled.
I then tried to derive from IDbSet but I'm not sure how to implement all needed methods.

Is there another way to achieve this goal without using an extension class?

Comment: What do you mean with "When I replace DbSet with CarRepository in my DbContext class it won't get filled"?

Comment: The property is null.

Comment: That's not a good idea anyway. A `DbSet` should have this single responsibility to provide an `IQueryable` to the application. Queries using `DbSet`s should be programmed in *services* that contain a context instance. Just think of the controversies if you need a query that addresses two (or more) `DbSet`s: which `DbSet` should own it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create your own single class(your repository) and put your methods like this.

```
    public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        private DbContext context;
        private DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }
    }
```